# Trying to build G Sheets scrip that will copy and paste a dynamic range within same spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to build a script that will allow me to copy and value paste a range from tab "robert" to tab "brendan". However, the range in "robert" is dynamic, so sometimes it will need to copy and paste A1:M3 or A1:M20. I'd also like it to append to the the first rows of the destination. So when run, the script looks for values on the source tab (robert), copies them, and pastes their values at the top of the destination (brendan) without overwriting existing data.

So far I've worked with the below script from a different thread:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Robert!A1:M100');
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Brendan!A4'), {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear();
}
```

The problem here is the script range is static, and it overwrites anything in the destination. I do like the clearing of the source though and the values paste. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Define the range using variables. Use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()) and [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastColumn()) Instead of hard-coding it.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var robWs = ss.getSheetByName("Robert");
var brenWs = ss.getSheetByName("Brendan");
var robLr = robWs.getLastRow()
var robLc = robWs.getLastColumn()

//range starts at row 1 and column 1 (A1), you may need to change accordingly
var vals = robWs.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).getValues;

//paste range also starts at A1. you can find the lr on this sheet and start the range there
brenWs.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).setValues(vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Robert');
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();//copies active range for source
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Brendan');
  dsr=4;//destination start row
  dsc=1;//destination start col
  dsa=2;//destination number of rows to append to
  drg=dsh.getRange(dsr,dsc,rg.getHeight(),rg.getWidth());
  var dvA=drg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(i<dsa){
      r.forEach(function(c,j){
        //only write data in destination for these rows if destination value is null
        if(dvA[i][j]='') {
          dvA[i][j]=c;
        }
      });
    }else{
      dvA[i][j]=c;
    }
  })
  drg.setValues(dvA);
}
```